# Visual Studio Auto-Format Broken

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, autoformatting

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 sp1 on Windows 7 Build 7100 32bit.

I've never had this problem before, even on different installs of Windows 7 RC.

when I finish a statement with a ';' or '}' or something, normally VS will auto format that line or block of code. It hasn't been for me.

I checked Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->General, and the 3 "Auto Format" check boxes are checked already. When I press the hot key to auto-format, it formats the source as expected.

Anyone have any idea why it's doing this?

What I have installed that might have something to do with this:
VS2008 SP1
SQL Server 2008 sp1
Office 2007

Thanks for the help

Comment: I had the autoformatter regularly doing nothing, mostly with more complex LINQ statements or nested collection/object initializers. Never really found out why.

Comment: Do you have any add-ins running that might be changing the way VS formats (ReSharper for example)?

Comment: Keep in mind there don't seem to be a lot of people reporting this problem. Maybe it's something fairly unique to you or your machine.

Comment: I had Windows 7 64bit installed on this same machine just before this with 0 problems. But I installed 32bit because I needed it for something for school that didn't have 64bit support.

I have not installed anything except what was previously mentioned. This is a fresh install. I haven't changed any settings or anything. And it's always doing this, from simple auto-tabbing when I hit enter, to however complex of a statement.

Comment: +1 my coworker has the similar problem, Ctrl+K+D doesn't work for him either

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to the problem. I actually tried reinstalling VS. I ended up reinstalling Win7, haven't had a problem since.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I found what I did wrong. I changed the tab settings from `Smart` to `Block`. Apparently, the smart tabs setting is what triggers the autocomplete when you close a block or toss in a `;`

Answer (score 1):

@Joel thanks I also have the problem that type`;` is not automatically formatted. Solution：Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Tabs ->Block

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on how changing the C/C++ tab for C# helps?

Comment: @Hayden In Visual Studio, you can set C/C++ or C# Text Editor that is separate, no effect each other