# Visual Studio 2010 Auto-Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting, autoformatting

I have the Productivity Power Tools extension installed on my machine, as well as VS 2010, but I seem to have developed a mysterious issue.

The IDE no longer auto-formats code when I enter a `;` or `}` which is quite annoying, I made particular use of the auto-format on `}` option.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156692/visual-studio-auto-format-broken), but that doesn't solve my problem either (the settings suggested there were already the same in my IDE).

I can't really offer more information at the minute, it was working yesterday, I came into work this morning and it's just stopped working, I haven't changed any settings at all. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: reboot, try /safemode to see if any extension is responsible, and if you can't figure out which one /resetsettings.

Answer (score 12):

Typically I've seen this when my code wouldn't build, or I'd missed a closing brace <kbd>}</kbd> somewhere (or something similar), usually above the code that I'm looking at.  Check that the code builds first just to remove it as a possibility, then try a forced auto format from the menu (Edit > Advanced > Format Document (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>)). Does it still not work?

This may not solve the issue, but should help refine the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ninjapig, the code was building, so no braces missing. I appeared to fix it late on Friday, but I have no idea how unfortunately, which is bugging me more than the original issue!

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me. Closing files and closing VS didn't help, and it's not the case of a missing bracket in the code. Somehow the Formatting setting got changed by some black magic in VS.

Here's where the setting is in VS 2010:
Tools ⇒ Options ⇒ Text Editor ⇒ C# ⇒ Formatting ⇒ Wrapping ⇒ Leave block on Single Line.

Uncheck the checkbox, and the lines will wrap when you enter the closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Old issue I know, but classic MS solution that hasn't been mentioned: **close the file and/or VS and start again** (sometimes just the file is enough, sometimes VS).

This happens a lot if you have the file open for a long time / lots of edits.  VS just gets fed up / bored / confused / overwhelmed.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. I've seen similar things after having VS open for a while, then opening a new instance (while the long running instance is still open), which resets all my UI settings. Annoying, but also another issue.