# VS Code: auto format html does not work

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, format

In VS Code I am having trouble in formatting HTML.

For example, I write a list of tags inline and I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and nothing happens.

I noticed this:

If I write:

```
<div><span><p></p></span></div>
```

nothing happens when I do the auto format.

If I write:

```
<div><div><div></div></div></div>
```

then it becomes:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

hope this will help you to help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Auto-Format Broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156692/visual-studio-auto-format-broken)

Comment: I think they may be related, but VSCode and Visual Studio are completely different codebases. I think the answer is that `span` tags are not considered "layout", and many editors choose not to "use" them when doing formatting

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem in my dev team. Please check or try the following things:

- Are the keyboard bindings correct?
- Is selected code language HTML?
- Have you restarted VS code?
- Begin a small piece of the formatting and then try again (for some reason it
  thinks its already correct.

Comment: I did everything but the second point. How do i check the code language? I thought vs code understands the language from the file extension..

Comment: Yes it will, but sometimes it helps reselecting it. You can do that in the bottom right corner. Next to the Smiley to tweet feedback

Comment: Nothing, i tried to reselect it but nothing is changed.

Comment: Can you add a piece of your HTML. Then I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: I edited the post. By the way, it happens also with an empty html file with only the three tags: <div><span><p></p></span></div>

Answer (score 2):

There are a certain list of tags that are ignored when auto formatting - these are defined in the setings.json file under

```
html.format.unformatted":
```

So go to settings (Command-Comma on a mac) and search for that setting and remove the tags you do want formatting.

The bad news is that it still doesn't format how I think it should - i.e. the  isn't indented inside the  but it at least puts it on a new line for you!

Comment: The problem is that it breaks the formatting for the rest of the page, since it starts a new line but at the beginning of the line... Is there something like `html.format.formatted` where you can add rules how to format specific elelment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a VS code bug. I installed the 1.17 and it worked very well https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17